# How to prove Green's function of $\partial_x^2 + \partial_y^2$ is $\frac{1}{2\pi}\log(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$?

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, greens-function

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function), the Green's function of $\partial_x^2 + \partial_y^2$ is $\frac{1}{2\pi}\log{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$.

But how to prove this ?

For $x \neq 0$ or $y \neq 0$, 
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\log(x^2 + y^2) = -\frac{2 (x^2 - y^2)}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}$$
Thus, 
$$\left(\partial_x^2 + \partial_y^2 \right)\frac{1}{2\pi}\log{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = 0$$

However, I cannot calculate the derivative for $x=0$ and $y=0$ because the numerator of $-\frac{2 (x^2 - y^2)}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}$ will expand.

So, my question is how to calculate $\left(\partial_x^2 + \partial_y^2 \right)\frac{1}{2\pi}\log{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}  $ for $x=0$ and $y=0$ to prove this function is Green's function of $\partial_x^2+\partial_y^2$.

====================Postscript=====================

I add this part according to the helpful comment of Cameron Williams.

In polar coordinates, 
$$\partial_x^2 + \partial_y^2 $$
$$= \partial_r^2 + \frac{1}{r}\partial_r+\frac{1}{r^2}\partial_\theta^2$$

and

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\log(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$$
$$=\frac{1}{\pi}\log{r}$$

Thus,

$$\left(\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+\frac{d^2}{dy^2}\right)\log(x^2 + y^2)$$
$$=\left(\partial_r^2 + \frac{1}{r}\partial_r\right)\frac{1}{\pi}\log{r}$$

Thing looks simpler.
However, I still don't understand why $\delta(x)\delta(y)$ will appear for $x=0$ and $y=0$.

Comment: Did you read the article you linked here — in particular the reference to a Dirac delta function? Why do you think the function should be differentiable at $(0,0)$?

Comment: I understand the problem. It should not be differentiable at $(0, 0)$ simply because function become Dirac delta function. But how people know it is Dirac delta function? This is my question of this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Dirac delta is a distribution characterized by the property that
$\newcommand{\rx}{x}$

$$ \int f(\rx) \delta(\rx) \, \mathrm{d}\rx = f(0) $$

holds for all nice test functions $f$. (Or more precisely, compactly supported smooth functions $f$.) And this is what we have to check. Now let $G$ be the 2D Green function. Then for each test function $f$, the distributional Laplacian $\Delta G$ (where of course $\Delta = \partial_1^2 + \partial_2^2$ is the Laplacian) satisfies

\begin{align*}
\int f(\rx) \Delta G(\rx) \, \mathrm{d}\rx
= \int G(\rx)\Delta f(\rx) \, \mathrm{d}\rx
= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{\|\rx\| > \epsilon} G(\rx)\Delta f(\rx) \, \mathrm{d}\rx. \tag{*}
\end{align*}

Since $G(\rx)\Delta f(\rx)$ is smooth and $\Delta G(\rx) = 0$ on the region $U_{\epsilon} = \{\rx\in\mathbb{R}^2:\|\rx\|>\epsilon\}$, applying Green's second identity gives

\begin{align*}
\int_{U_{\epsilon}} G(\rx)\Delta f(\rx) \, \mathrm{d}\rx
&= \int_{U_{\epsilon}} \left( G(\rx)\Delta f(\rx) - f(\rx)\Delta G(\rx) \right) \, \mathrm{d}\rx \\
&= \int_{\partial U_{\epsilon}} \left( G(\rx)\nabla f(\rx) - f(\rx)\nabla G(\rx) \right) \cdot \mathrm{n}(\rx) \, \sigma(\mathrm{d}x),
\end{align*}

where $\sigma$ is the surface measure of $\partial U_{\epsilon}$ and $\mathrm{n}(\rx)$ is the *outward* unit normal to $\partial U_{\epsilon}$ at $\rx$. But since

$$\nabla G(\rx) = \frac{\rx}{2\pi\|\rx\|^2} $$

and $\partial U_{\epsilon}$ is the inward-oriented circle of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $0$, we have $\mathrm{n}(\rx) = -\rx/\epsilon$ and hence

\begin{align*}
&\int_{\partial U_{\epsilon}} \left( G(\rx)\nabla f(\rx) - f(\rx)\nabla G(\rx) \right) \cdot \mathrm{n}(\rx) \, \sigma(\mathrm{d}\rx) \\
&\quad = \int_{\partial U_{\epsilon}} \left( \frac{\log \epsilon}{2\pi}\nabla f(\rx) - f(\rx) \frac{\rx}{2\pi \epsilon^2} \right) \cdot \left( - \frac{\rx}{\epsilon} \right) \, \sigma(\mathrm{d}\rx) \\
&\qquad = \frac{1}{2\pi\epsilon} \int_{\partial U_{\epsilon}} f(\rx) \, \sigma(\mathrm{d}\rx) - \frac{\log \epsilon}{2\pi} \int_{\partial U_{\epsilon}} \nabla f(\rx)\cdot \frac{\rx}{\epsilon} \, \sigma(\mathrm{d}\rx).
\end{align*}

Since the first integral in the last line is the average of $f$ over $\partial U_{\epsilon}$, by continuity of $f$,

$$ \frac{1}{2\pi\epsilon} \int_{\partial U_{\epsilon}} f(\rx) \, \sigma(\mathrm{d}\rx) \xrightarrow[\epsilon \to 0^+]{} f(0). $$

On the other hand,

\begin{align*}
\left| \frac{\log \epsilon}{2\pi} \int_{\partial U_{\epsilon}} \nabla f(\rx)\cdot \frac{\rx}{\epsilon} \, \sigma(\mathrm{d}\rx) \right|
&\leq \frac{\log (1/\epsilon)}{2\pi} \int_{\partial U_{\epsilon}} \|\nabla f\|_{\infty} \, \sigma(\mathrm{d}\rx) \\
&= (\epsilon \log (1/\epsilon)) \|\nabla f\|_{\infty},
\end{align*}

which converges to $0$ as $\epsilon \to 0^+$. Therefore the limit in $\text{(*)}$ is computed as

$$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{\|\rx\| > \epsilon} G(\rx)\Delta f(\rx) \, \mathrm{d}\rx = f(0), $$

which tells that the distribution $\Delta G$ is exactly the Dirac delta.

Comment: I noticed you use `\mathrm` a lot so `\newcommand{\x}{\mathrm{x}}` might prove very helpful to you

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish, I did not know that `\newcommand` can be used in MathJax. Thank you!